# How to append list of values into a desired string format?

Tags: python, string, list, append

I have two lists like below. I want to convert the list of values into a desired string format like `'123,1345;2345,890;'`. I tried to use loop and tried to append as list but how do I convert that into a string format.

```
l1 = [123,4567,80,3456,879]
l2=[98,789,5674,678,9087]

out=[]
for i,j in zip(l1,l2):
    out.append(str(j)+','+str(i)+';')
print(out)
['98,123;', '789,4567;', '5674,80;', '678,3456;', '9087,879;']
```

Excepted output:-

```
'98,123;789,4567;5674,80;678,3456;9087,879;'
```

Comment: Just change print(out) to print(''.join(out))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l1 = [123,4567,80,3456,879]
l2=[98,789,5674,678,9087]

out=[]
for i,j in zip(l1,l2):
    out.append(str(j)+','+str(i))
print(';'.join(out) + ";")
```

You can join your list with ; to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension that you then unpack into a single *print()* call.

```
l1 = [123,4567,80,3456,879]
l2 = [98,789,5674,678,9087]

print(*[f'{b},{a};' for a, b in zip(l1, l2)], sep='')
```

**Output:**

```
98,123;789,4567;5674,80;678,3456;9087,879;
```

Or, with a generator:

```
print(''.join(f'{b},{a};' for a, b in zip(l1, l2)))
```